# Comparing 3 numbers by taking user input in Java

Tags: java

Is this code runnable? I'm getting an error

```
big.java:10: error: incompatible types
                a = in.nextLine();
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
big.java:14: error: incompatible types
                b = in.nextLine();
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
big.java:18: error: incompatible types
                c = in.nextLine();
                               ^
  required: int
  found:    String
3 errors
```

---

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class big    

    {
        public static void main(String args[])  
    {
                    int a;
                    int b;
                    int c;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter value for a");
        a = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your entered value is" +a);

        System.out.println("Enter value for b");
        b = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your entered value is" +b);

        System.out.println("Enter Value for c");
        c = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your entered value is" +c);

    if((a>b)&&(a>c))    
{

System.out.println("The biggest number is" +a);

}

else if((b>a)&&(b>c))   
{

System.out.println("The biggest number is" +b);

}

else    
{

System.out.println("The biggest number is" +c);

}

}

}
```

Comment: what you have put above is first unreadble. please edit and correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `in.nextLine()` returns a String object, and by trying to assign this into the a variable, you're effectively trying to stuff a String object into an int variable. Since this is not allowed, the compiler is complaining. Use Scanner's `nextInt()` method instead, since it returns an int.

```
a = in.nextInt();
```

And by the way, your question sub-title is pretty bad. Of course your code is un-runnable, as your Java compiler is already telling you.

Comment: sir, i'm new to java. Plus i'm new to this website. I'm unaware of how a title exactly should be. I would try keeping a nice title from next time. thanks for your kind help. Now it's running when i used 
a = in.nextInt()

Comment: @Harshit: it's not a matter of new to this or that. It's common sense, since you already know that your code is not running. A bit distracting is all.

Answer (score 1):

Use in.nextInt() ; not in.nextLine()